# r programming- in a data frame how change any number to the column name

Tags: r, dataframe

A. I have a large xts object which I converted to a data frame so that I could change any number in a column to the first part of the column name.
i.e.

```
Date,  A-B, A-C, A-D, B-A, B-C, B-D,... 
1/1/11 N/A N/A 0.012 N/A 0.055 N/A 
1/2/11 0.25 N/A N/A 0.456 N/A 0.12
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
Date,  A-B, A-C, A-D, B-A, B-C, B-D,... 
1/1/11 N/A  N/A   A   N/A   B   N/A 
1/2/11  A   N/A   N/A   B   N/A   B
```

The code I used was:

```
allwins.sec1 <- apply(allwins.sec, 2, function(i) ifelse(is.na(allwins.sec[,i]), NA, gsub("-.*$", "",colnames(allwins.sec[,i]))))
```

But I'm getting an error "Error in [.data.frame(allwins.sec, , i) : undefined columns selected" Any thoughts on how to fix this?

B. My follow up to this is to total all the A's, B's, C, ... and sort from most to least. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly :

```
cols <- sub('-.*', '', names(df)[-1])
mat <- which(!is.na(df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
df[-1][mat] <- cols[mat[, 2]]
df

#    Date A-B A-C A-D B-A B-C B-D
#1 1/1/11 N/A N/A   A N/A   B N/A
#2 1/2/11   A N/A N/A   B N/A   B
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/11", "1/2/11"), `A-B` = c("N/A", 
"0.25"), `A-C` = c("N/A", "N/A"), `A-D` = c("0.012", "N/A"), 
`B-A` = c("N/A", "0.456"), `B-C` = c("0.055", "N/A"), `B-D` = c("N/A", 
"0.12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df[df == 'N/A'] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  1. I incorrectly stated N/A when I should have stated NA.  Which might be why running your code I get the following error:  Error in x[[v]][thisvar] <- if (N > 1L) value[n + seq_len(nv)] else value :  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: @Doug You can try updated answer for real `NA`'s. If it still doesn't work you need to provide data in a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) format using `dput`.

Comment: @Doug Did you try the updated answer. Did it work for you?